# Zenity Calendar Input

Tags: bash, calendar, dialog, zenity

So i am trying to do a Calendar which can be used as a notepad for each day, like a reminder.
I was wondering if there is a way that when the user click on a date , the program open an --entry text window and ask for the desired reminder. then when selecting the same date again, the reminder is still there. Thanks , here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

function Ddate()
{
    zenity --info \
    --title "Date and Time" \
    --text "Today is $(date)"
}

function Dcalendar()
{
    zenity --calendar \
    --title "Calendar" 
}

function DReminder()
{
    --title "Reminder" \
    --entry-text "Birthday/Events..."
}

function DDelete()
{
    zenity --entry-text "Enter Path" > \
    --title "DELETE"
}

while true;
do
choice="$(zenity --height 275 --width 450 \
--list \
--title="Menu" \
--column="Function" --column="Description" \
    Date 'Display the actual date and time.' \
    Calendar 'Display an interactive calendar.' \
    Delete 'Let you delete a file.' \
    Exit 'To quit this script.')"

case $choice in
    Date) Ddate;;
    Calendar) Dcalendar;;
    Delete) Ddelete;;
    Exit) break;;

esac

done
```